# Show data base on combo box selection

Tags: vb.net

> > ModuleName,ModuleCode,LecturerName
> >
> > ABC, 123,  Melanie
> >
> > DEF,456, Jack

Now my combo box data loaded from my Access database, now i'm trying to print 2nd & 3rd column data based on the selection from combo box into each respective label.

Example:

> > ABC is selected
> >
> > lblModuleCode should show 123
> >
> > lblLecturerName should show Melanie

I've tried using the code below to populate the result.

Comment: Firstly, displaying something in a `Label` is not "printing". Secondly, what code? Finally, you should look into data-binding.  If you bind the `ComboBox` and the two `Labels` to the same `DataTable` then you don't need any further code to make the `Labels` display the selected data.

Answer (score 0):

@Jmcilhinney says write you should bind labels with same database then no need to write any code. It will auto update with combo box selection changed.